# scroll position of html object tag

Tags: html, pdf, object, scroll, position

I am working on a project that pulls in a pdf document via the object tag `<object data="the-url-to-the-document" class="ppa_document" type="application/pdf"></object>` and I want to find out if the user has scrolled to the bottom of that embedded document to then enable the "i agree" checkbox.  I tried it will the jQuery .scroll() function but that didn't work.  Any suggestions?  Considering Adobe Acrobat is a totally different interface, it may not be possible.  On the other hand, it does become part of the DOM, so maybe it is possible!?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? If so can you help me with the answer?

Answer (score 1):

For most DOM elements you could use the scrollTop property. For example:

```
var position = document.getElementById('elemId').scrollTop;
```

However, what happens inside of the <object> tag is a different story... In case of PDF files, Acrobat Reader is handling the scroll bars and I do not believe there is an API to get the scroll bar position. However, please correct me if I am wrong, as I'd love to know myself if there is such a thing.